# Five cards are randomly dealt from a standard deck of cards. Show the probability distribution of the # of cards that are face cards or aces.

Tags: probability

Five cards are randomly dealt from a standard deck of cards.   Show the probability distribution of the number of cards that are either face cards or aces.

You can create a table or not.

Comment: This should be a straightforward application of counting principles or an even more straightforward application of the [hypergeometric distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_distribution).  Where exactly did you get stuck in your own personal attempts at solving this problem?

Comment: This question was given to me. It asks to put this into a table. I'm not used to doing this type of question when dealing with cards that request face or aces. Do you have a solution to this problem.

Comment: Yes.  The question is whether I consider it worth giving you the answer directly.  I would much rather see you put a bit of effort into solving the problem yourself because otherwise I am not confident that you will have learned anything.  Lets break down the definitions... How many cards in the deck are facecards or aces? (*remember, face cards are jacks, queens, and kings*)

Comment: I have put a lot of effort into this question (several hours at that)  which Is why i'm asking for help. There are 12 face cards and 4 aces in a deck. 16 in a deck of 52 cards.

Comment: Next leading question: How many cards are *neither* face nor ace?  Okay... so, lets look at a specific entry of the table... let us count how many hands contain exactly one ace or face.  How many ways are there to choose the one specific ace or face that appears?  How many ways are there to choose the remaining four nonace-nonface cards?  Out of how many ways to have chosen five cards ignoring the question of how many face/ace cards there are?

Comment: 36 cards remain. 1/5 is the hand that contains 1 face or ace.

Comment: "1/5 is the hand that contains 1 face or ace"   I am not looking for a ratio of the handsize that is face-or-ace., I am trying to lead you to a ratio of the *number of hands possible* with a face-or-ace.  Think using binomial coefficients.  There are $52$ cards total, and there are $\binom{52}{5}$ possible different hands of size five, each of which is equally likely to occur.  We are trying to find what percentage of those possible hands have exactly one face-or-ace

Comment: If we have $n$ objects and we want to choose $k$ of them, this can be done in $\binom{n}{k}=\frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}$ number of ways (*read aloud as "n choose k"*).  If we have $36$ cards which aren't face-or-ace, and we want to choose $4$ of them... how many ways can this be done?

Comment: Sorry but is there no way you provide me with some answers. I came here for some help with the solution, not a step by step help. If I knew the answers then I could fully understand how to do the question next time. I have been working on this question for several hours now and need to move on.

Comment: If you just want the answer, then look at my very first comment and take a look at the wikipedia page... "*the hypergeometric distribution is a discrete probability distribution that describes the probability of $k$ successes (random draws for which the object drawn has a specified feature) in $n$ draws, without replacement, from a finite population of size $N$ that contains exactly $K$ objects with that feature, wherein each draw is either a success or a failure.*" and has pmf $Pr(X=k)=\dfrac{\binom{K}{k}\binom{N-K}{n-k}}{\binom{N}{n}}$

Comment: I'm just not sure how to apply this question to this equation. That is why I came to this website, so that I could be shown how to solve this answer in a way that someone who struggles with math could see and understand.

Comment: There are $K$ face-or-ace cards.  There are $N$ cards in the deck total.  We are drawing $n$ cards into our hand.  Each of those numbers are implied by the problem and we have talked about already in the comments here.  We make our table and have an entry for each possible value of $k\in\{0,1,2,3,4,5\}$.  The only thing left is comprehending the words I am saying and doing the arithmetic if its necessary (*usually isn't for most classes, just leave it in an unsimplified form*)

Comment: So it should look like this = (16/1) (52/36-16/1)/(52/36) for 1 card value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is such a table for a related *but different* question of instead counting how many Spades ($\spadesuit$) are in our hand of five cards.

Let $X$ represent the random variable counting the number of spades in our hand when drawing five random cards from a well-shuffled standard deck of $52$ cards without replacement.

Note: there are $13$ spades and there are $39$ non-spade cards.

$\begin{array}{|c|c|c|}\hline k&Pr(X=k)&\text{approximation}\\\hline 0&\dfrac{\binom{13}{0}\binom{39}{5}}{\binom{52}{5}}&0.222
\\\hline 1&\dfrac{\binom{13}{1}\binom{39}{4}}{\binom{52}{5}}&0.411
\\\hline 2&\dfrac{\binom{13}{2}\binom{39}{3}}{\binom{52}{5}}&0.274
\\\hline 3&\dfrac{\binom{13}{3}\binom{39}{2}}{\binom{52}{5}}&0.082
\\\hline 4&\dfrac{\binom{13}{4}\binom{39}{1}}{\binom{52}{5}}&0.011
\\\hline 5&\dfrac{\binom{13}{5}\binom{39}{0}}{\binom{52}{5}}&0.0005\\\hline\end{array}$

*Note:* Here $\binom{n}{r}$ represents the [binomial coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient) "*n choose r*", the number of ways of selecting $r$ objects from a set of $n$ distinct objects.  It is not division.  Instead $\binom{n}{r}=\frac{n!}{r!(n-r)!}$ so for example $\binom{7}{3}=\frac{7!}{3!4!}=35$

---

The idea behind where this formula comes is that there are $\binom{52}{5}$ equally likely five-card hands.  When counting the number of hands with $k$ spades, we choose which $k$ spades those happen to be in $\binom{13}{k}$ number of ways.  Multiplying that by the $\binom{39}{5-k}$ number of ways of choosing the remaining $5-k$ non-spade cards gives us the total number of hands with $k$ spades as $\binom{13}{k}\binom{39}{5-k}$.  Taking the ratio then gives us the probability of it occurring.

This example and yours both follow the [hypergeometric distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_distribution).  There are only very minor changes to be made to find the answer to your exact question compared to this one.

Comment: How would I implement the question of the probability distribution of "either face cards or aces" into this table.

Comment: In the above table we were interested in $13$ spades.  In the table you want to make, instead we are interested in $16$ face-or-ace cards...  In the above table there were $39$ non-spade cards.  In the table you want to make there are.........  _______